# How to keep cells "paired" with query results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using an importrange query from other sheet to filter data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FbeoKhiJ3jqYXqfIgAK_tHXPZ_Z1Xrm33ulu9gomXuE/edit?usp=sharing

The "colors" sheet has data populated from query ("items" sheet) and users are allowed to write comments on each row.

Problem: if row order is changed on "items" sheet, the "colors" sheet row order 
 will be lost and any previous comment will not match the correct row.

How can I prevent this? Is there a way to keep paired query row results and comments? Maybe using timestamp as a reference?

At the moment sheet "colors" contains a correct pairing, once a row is inserted between "items", the pairing is lost

Comment: Related: 1) [Align the rows of one sheet with the rows of an imported sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92943/88163) 2) [Locking cell positions to another cell if one column is using IMPORTRANGE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85954/88163)

Comment: Added a ID/Key to "item" sheet, however I don't understand how this would work even when adding a "key"/id: what happens if row 3 is deleted in "item" sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Suggested setup

Use two sheets, Import and Entry

1. Import sheet

   - Use to import the data to your spreadsheet,

     - Use IMPORTRANGE on this sheet
2. Entry sheet

   - Use to capture, insert comments

     - Add a column for key/id. Add the key/id manually, by writing one by one, using paste as values, a macro/script, add-on or an app that uses the Google Sheets API.

       - Related threads:

         - [Copying data to *and from* another sheet based on the month of a date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89137/88163)
         - [Sync multiple cells so that if any one of them is changed, the others change as well](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92966/88163)
         - [Sync two cells value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104955/88163)
     - Use a lookup formula to get the required values from the import sheet by using the key/id column for the lookup, you could use VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH among other methods.

       - Related threads:

         - [Align the rows of one sheet with the rows of an imported sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92943/88163)
     - Add the columns that will hold the comments

## "FAQ"

- What will happen if a row is deleted from the source sheet (the one that was imported)?

  - The cells on the Entry Sheet that use lookup will show #N/A but the key/id and the columns that hold the comments will remain in place.

Comment: Getting closer to the solution. One more question: there should be a way to keep the IDs updated in both "tables", otherwise manual update is required vanishing benefits. For instance, I could use a cell with timestamp in the "import sheet", BUT this should be stored somehow in the "entry sheet" when a comment is inserted....

Comment: I could run a script that will copy the timestamp from "import sheet" to "entry sheet" each time a new comment is created

Comment: @Riccardo If you don't want to manually update the keys/ids between sheets, definitely you should use something that use Google Apps Script or Google Sheets API.

Comment: @Riccardo I added a link to a related thread that I found by searching "two way sync" (I posted an answer to it some time ago)